# get document children with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to get document first children (which means: body, html, head etc..)
This code line works:

```
var x = document.body.children;
```

but this one does not:

```
var x = document.children;
```

how can I get the first childs of the document without running on all elements **using JAVASCRIPT only**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document element is appropriately called `documentElement`. In HTML, this is the `<html>` tag.

So:

```
document.documentElement.children
```

This should give you a list of length 2, with the first being the `<head>` and the second being the `<body>`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `childNodes`:

```
document.childNodes
```

Note that `document`'s children are `<DOCTYPE>` and `<html>`

Comment: And I would link to MDN docs, but they appear to be down. ;-\ Here's to hoping they return: [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes)

Comment: @BradChristie exactly.. even <DOCTYPE> has `childNodes` property!

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
document.childNodes
```

you get the docType and the html.

If you use

```
document.childNodes[1].childNodes
```

(supposing you have a doctype)

then you get the header and the body.